# What happens if you delete the root user?

Tags: sudo, root, users

What happens if you run

```
sudo deluser root
```

will sudo still work, and will the system still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delete an user if there are processes currently running as that user, which in the case of `root`, is **always**.
You could manually delete the entries in `/etc/{passwd,shadow,group}`, but
depending on the settings in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, there might be alternate sources of the root account, so things will continue to work. If you then remove the alternate sources in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` so that only these files are used (by keeping only `compat`):

```
passwd: compat
group: compat
shadow: compat
```

Then things will start to break:

```
$ sudo -i
sudo: unknown user: root
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

It might even lead to an unbootable system; you'll have to go back and fix with a live USB or single user mode.